# Rspec - 2 output with logs

Tags: ruby, rspec

Using Rspec, I want get 2 output formats by test. My tests have a `Logger` for console - it's command `puts`. So when I write

```
rspec my_example_spec.rb --format html -o results.html
```

I got html file without logs (just passed and failed results) and logs in console.
When I write

```
rspec my_example_spec.rb --format h > results.html
```

I got html with my logs and results, but empty console. So, how I can get both output with logs?

Comment: Use `tee`: `rspec my_example_spec.rb --format h | tee results.html`

Comment: @mdesantis, no point in duplicate posting an answer and a comment. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee`:

```
rspec my_example_spec.rb --format h | tee results.html
```

Comment: so you want a different output for console? it's not possible

Comment: What you likely want is `rspec my_example_spec.rb --format html -o results.html | tee non-html-output.txt`. You need to pass the '-o' flag to send HTML output to file specifically, anything else from rspec tests like data that gets written to stdout/stderr goes to console, which you can then tee. If you like a specific format in the console, you can also pass that other format but not include the '-o' flag, e.g.  `rspec my_example_spec.rb --format progress --format html -o results.html | tee results-as-non-html.txt`. Old versions of RSpec may not support the multiple formats with save to file.